# cumsum only within groups?

Tags: matlab, vector

Lets say I have 2 vectors:

```
a=[0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1];
b=[1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3];
```

For every group of numbers in b I want to cumsum, so that the result should look like that:

```
c=[1 3;2 1;3 3]
```

That means that I have for the ones in b 3 ones in a, for group two in b I have only one one in a etc.

Comment: It sounds like you want to `sum` as opposed to `cumsum`...

Comment: What you describe is NOT cumsum. Also you didn't specify `a` - but if it's a "logical index" you could do `tmp = b(a==1)` which takes you "half way".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a solution where `b` can be anything, then a combination of `hist` and `unique` will help:

```
num = unique(b(logical(a))); %# identify the numbers in b with non-zero counts
cts = hist(b(logical(a)),num); %# count
c = [num(:),cts(:)]; %# combine.
```

If you want the first column of `c` to go from 1 to the maximum of `b`, then you can rewrite the first line as `num=1:max(b)`, and you'll also get rows in `c` where the counts are zero.

Answer (score 4):

There have been some complicated answers so far. Try `accumarray(b',a')`.

Comment: Way better use of Matlab than the other answers posted so far.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: I generally try to promote `accumarray` as much as possible. However, `accumarray` won't work if `b` has negative entries, or is e.g. `[1 2000000000000]`, or is not all integers. For simple counting, `hist` is much more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `b` is monotonically increasing by 1:

```
c = cell2mat(transpose(arrayfun( @(x) [ x sum(a(find( b == x ))) ], min(b):max(b), 'UniformOutput',false)))
```

should give the right answer in a one liner format, or:

```
for ii=min(b):max(b)
  II = find( b == ii );
  v = sum(a(II));
  c(ii,:) = [ii v];
end
```

which is a bit easier to read.  Hope this helps.